# Is it bad SEO practice to link to hundreds of internal pages on one page?

Tags: seo

I have a site with 200 pages.

On each page, I would like to set up links to the rest 199 pages. I did this because I want my users to link to other pages easily.

But is this a very bad practice for SEO? Will Google hate this?

Comment: Not sure whether google would hate it, but if I was a visitor and there were links to 200 pages, I think I might find it a bit overwhelming...

Comment: @Steve I used JavaScript to split them into pages. But google bot would not know it :(

Comment: Your question can be answered by answering this question. "Do my visitors need the links and they are useful or am I putting them there only for SEO reasons?"

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad for SEO to link to other pages. In fact, internal linking is good for SEO. You're making it easier for the users to find what they're looking for and Google loves this. Having said that, only link to relevant pages. 200 pages sounds a lot to me. Choose the most important to you and the users to link to. Also take a good look at your URL structure and link to pages above/below the current page. Example:

`example.com/landing-page` Links to `example.com/landing-page/linking`

`example.com/landing-page/linking` links to `example.com/landing-page` **and links to** `example.com/landing-page/linking/internal`

`example.com/landing-page/linking/internal` links to `example.com/landing-page`

Another reason not to link to too many pages is the amount of link juice you're spreading then. Decide for yourself what are the most important pages (which you want to be well ranked in Google), those pages deserve to have more links.

Answer (score 1):

Is this bad for SEO? Presumably. Yes.

Any site should be organized in a hierarchical way using directories and pages including topic/category pages. If done correctly, any user should be able to navigate your site to find what they want. You can also consider linking from page to page where you feel the user may "also be interested in" the topic.

Search engines expect you to follow tradition and do what any webmaster would do. Anything else often does not work. The reason is simple. Most sites follow tradition and this expectancy is written into the SE code. Being an outlier often does not pay dividends.

Google and presumably Bing examine link patterns looking for manipulation. Google is exceptionally good at this. Linking to every page on every page would likely be seen as manipulation. You do not want this.

Years ago, I had a site with millions of pages. I found it impossible to link to each page but did link to about 100 similar pages on each page. This did not work well. If I had followed tradition, creating category pages would created 10s of thousands of low quality pages and far too cumbersome for users. Instead, I needed to create a navigation method that allowed users and Google to drill down all of my pages. I created several ways to link to "virtual" category pages using a CGI script with parameters and a noindex tag. This worked well.

I am not recommending this of course, however, the lesson learned was that too many links added to the page was bad for SEO. However, adding a few "more focused" links was good for SEO.

If your site is about 200 pages as you use in your example, you should easily be able to organize your site using traditional methods that will work well for search. I always recommend following tradition where possible.